# Optimize Oracle Between Date Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, between

I got an oracle SQL query that selects entries of the current day like so:

```
SELECT   [fields] 
FROM     MY_TABLE T 
WHERE    T.EVT_END BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) 
                       AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 86399/86400
  AND    T.TYPE = 123
```

Whereas the `EVT_END` field is of type `DATE` and `T.TYPE` is a `NUMBER(15,0)`.

Im sure with increasing size of the table data (and ongoing time), the date constraint will decrease the result set by a much larger factor than the type constraint. (Since there are a very limited number of types)

So the basic question arising is, what's the best index to choose to make the selection on the current date faster. I especially wonder what the advantages and disadvantages of a functional index on `TRUNC(T.EVT_END)` to a normal index on `T.EVT_END` would be. When using a functional index the query would look something like that:

```
SELECT   [fields] 
FROM     MY_TABLE T 
WHERE    TRUNC(T.EVT_END) = TRUNC(SYSDATE) 
  AND    T.TYPE = 123
```

Because other queries use the mentioned date constraints without the additional type selection (or maybe with some other fields), multicolumn indexes wouldn't help me a lot.

Thanks, I'd appreciate your hints.

Comment: you forget include EVT_END data type.

Comment: If partitioning is an option, daily interval partitioning might be a perfect fit here.

Comment: The safe way of getting all the dates and times in a range is (pseudo code): `d >= start AND d < (end + 1 day)`. This works even when `d` is the very last fraction of the last second of the end date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Results**

If your index is cached, a function-based index performs best.  If your index is not cached, a compressed function-based index performs best.

Below are the relative times generated by my test code.  Lower is better.  You cannot compare the numbers between cached and non-cached, they are totally different tests.

```
                 In cache      Not in cache
Regular          120           139
FBI              100           138
Compressed FBI   126           100
```

I'm not sure why the FBI performs better than the regular index.  (Although it's probably related to what you said about equality predicates versus range.  You can see that the regular index has an extra "FILTER" step in its explain plan.)  The compressed FBI has some additional overhead to uncompress the blocks.  This small amount of extra CPU time is relevant when everything is already in memory, and CPU waits are most important.  But when nothing is cached, and IO is more important, the reduced space of the compressed FBI helps a lot.

**Assumptions**

There seems to be a lot of confusion about this question.  The way I read it, you only care about this one specific query, and you want to know whether a function-based index or a regular index will be faster.

I assume you do not care about other queries that may benefit from this index, additional time spent to maintain the index, if the developers remember to use it, or whether or not the optimizer chooses the index.  (If the optimizer doesn't choose the index, which I think is unlikely, you can add a hint.)  Let me know if any of these assumptions are wrong.

**Code**

```
--Create tables. 1 = regular, 2 = FBI, 3 = Compressed FBI
create table my_table1(evt_end date, type number) nologging;
create table my_table2(evt_end date, type number) nologging;
create table my_table3(evt_end date, type number) nologging;

--Create 1K days, each with 100K values
begin
    for i in 1 .. 1000 loop
        insert /*+ append */ into my_table1
        select sysdate + i - 500 + (level * interval '1' second), 1
        from dual connect by level <= 100000;

        commit;
    end loop;
end;
/
insert /*+ append */ into my_table2 select * from my_table1;
insert /*+ append */ into my_table3 select * from my_table1;

--Create indexes
create index my_table1_idx on my_table1(evt_end);
create index my_table2_idx on my_table2(trunc(evt_end));
create index my_table3_idx on my_table3(trunc(evt_end)) compress;

--Gather statistics
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'MY_TABLE1');
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'MY_TABLE2');
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'MY_TABLE3');
end;
/

--Get the segment size.
--This shows the main advantage of a compressed FBI, the lower space.
select segment_name, bytes/1024/1024/1024 GB
from dba_segments
where segment_name like 'MY_TABLE__IDX'
order by segment_name;

SEGMENT_NAME     GB
MY_TABLE1_IDX    2.0595703125
MY_TABLE2_IDX    2.0478515625
MY_TABLE3_IDX    1.1923828125


--Test block.
--Uncomment different lines to generate 6 different test cases.
--Regular, Function-based, and Function-based compressed.  Both cached and not-cached.
declare
    v_count number;
    v_start_time number;
    v_total_time number := 0;
begin
    --Uncomment two lines to test the server when it's "cold", and nothing is cached.
    for i in 1 .. 10 loop
        execute immediate 'alter system flush buffer_cache';
    --Uncomment one line to test the server when it's "hot", and everything is cached.
    --for i in 1 .. 1000 loop

        v_start_time := dbms_utility.get_time;

        SELECT COUNT(*)
        INTO   V_COUNT
        --#1: Regular
        FROM   MY_TABLE1 T 
        WHERE  T.EVT_END BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 86399/86400;
        --#2: Function-based
        --FROM   MY_TABLE2 T 
        --WHERE  TRUNC(T.EVT_END) = TRUNC(SYSDATE);
        --#3: Compressed function-based
        --FROM   MY_TABLE3 T 
        --WHERE  TRUNC(T.EVT_END) = TRUNC(SYSDATE);

        v_total_time := v_total_time + (dbms_utility.get_time - v_start_time);
    end loop;

    dbms_output.put_line('Seconds: '||v_total_time/100);
end;
/
```

**Test Methodology**

I ran each block at least 5 times, alternated between run types (in case something was running on my machine only part of the time), threw out the high and the low run times, and averaged them.  The code above does not include all that logic, since it would take up 90% of this answer.

**Other Things to Consider**

There are still many other things to consider.  My code assumes the data is inserted in a very index-friendly order.  Things will be totally different if this is not true, as compression may not help at all.

Probably the best solution to this problem is to avoid it completely with partitioning.  For reading the same amount of data, a full table scan is much faster than an index read because it uses multi-block IO.  But there are some downsides to partitioning, like the large amount of money
required to buy the option, and extra maintenance tasks.  For example, creating partitions ahead of time, or using interval partitioning (which has some other weird issues), gathering stats, deferred segment creation, etc.

Ultimately, you will need to test this yourself.  But remember that testing even such a simple choice is difficult.  You need realistic data, realistic tests, and a realistic environment.  Realistic data is much harder than it sounds.  With indexes, you cannot simply copy the data and build the indexes at once.  `create table my_table1 as select * from` and `create index ...` will create a different index than if you create the table and perform a bunch of inserts and deletes in a specific order.

Answer (score 4):

Your index should be TYPE, EVT_END.

```
CREATE INDEX PIndex
ON MY_TABLE (TYPE, EVT_END)
```

The optimizer plan will first go through this index to find the TYPE=123 section.  Then under TYPE=123, it will have the EVT_END timestamps sorted, so it can search the b-tree for the first date in the range, and go through the dates sequentially until a data is out of the range.

Comment: You might have overlooked the part where I disqualified a multicolumn index in the rush to a fast answer. My main question is how a index on `EVT_END` would differ to one on `TRUNC(EVT_END)`. However your answer helped in convincing me of the possibilities of the normal B-Tree for sequential scans.

Comment: There is no problem with a multicolumn index just because other queries use the EVT_END without TYPE.  Why not have both an index on just EVT_END, and anther index on TYPE,EVT_END?

Comment: Because we don't want to add index we don't really need. They're getting way too large over time and we have limited resources. But even if, do you have an idea about the other point (functional index vs. normal one)?

Comment: the function index may (and its only a MAY) reduce overall query IO. why? the clustering factor could well improve. This means that you should see IO drop if the data in the table isn't naturally ordered in EVT_END order. The drop in IO may not be significant when dealing with the overall time though. also have you tried indexing (TYPE, EVT_END) with queries that dont use TYPE? the reason i ask is that you said its very low cardinality, so you may find the queries use an index skip scan. another option is index (EVT_END, TYPE). not as efficient for this query but still may be acceptable.

Comment: @DazzaL Using a function based index to reduce the clustering factor is an interesting idea.  I'm guessing the answer to this question involves comparing the performance benefit of a better clustering factor with the downside of FBIs being much larger.  You should expand on your idea in a new answer.

Comment: a FBI wouldn't be larger at all. its still storing just a date so still 7 bytes per date.

Comment: Yes but there are way less different indexed values (one per day vs. approximately one for each entry). Additionally during access a simple equality is used and no need for seeking through a range. (potentially leading to a lot of jumps in memory)

Comment: @DazzaL You're right.  I thought that FBIs were always larger, but I can't reproduce that.  Not sure where I got that idea from.  Thanks.

Comment: Very helpful! Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Based on the query above the functional index will provide no value.  For a functional index to be used the predicate in the query would need to be written as follows:

```
SELECT [fields] 
FROM MY_TABLE T 
WHERE TRUNC(T.EVT_END) BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 86399/86400
  AND T.TYPE = 123
```

The functional index on the column EVT_END, is being ignored.  It would be better to have a normal index on the EVT_END date.  For a functional index to be used the left hand of the condition must match the declaration of the functional index.  I would probably write the query as:

```
SELECT [fields] 
FROM MY_TABLE T 
WHERE T.EVT_END BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE+1)
  AND T.TYPE = 123
```

And I would create the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX bla on MY_TABLE( EVT_END )
```

This is assuming you are trying to find the events that ended within a day.

Comment: Note: there is no need for the BETWEEN if your using TRUNC(T.EVT_END) as it will only ever match or not match TRUNC(SYSDATE).

Comment: @Stu I believe his question already implied that he would change the predicate: "...moving the TRUNC function around the T.EVT_END...".  (Although it might be helpful if the question was modified a little to make it clearer exactly what he wants to compare.)

Answer (score 1):

@S1lence:
I believe there would be a considerable time of thought behind this question being asked by you. And, I took a lot of time to post my answer here, as I don't like posting any guesses for answers.
I would like to share my websearch experience on this choice of normal Index on a date column against FBIs.
Based on my understanding on the *link* below, if you are about to use TRUNC function **for sure**, then you can strike out the option of normal index, as this consulting web space says that:
*Even though the column may have an index, the trunc built-in function will invalidate the index, causing sub-optimal execution with unnecessary I/O.*
I suppose that clears all. You've to go with FBI if you gonna use `TRUNC` for sure. Please let me know if my reply makes sense.

[Oracle SQL Tuning with function-based indexes](http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_index_scan_fbi_sql.htm)

Cheers,
Lakshmanan C.

Answer (score 1):

The deicion over whether or not to use a function-based index should be driven by how you plan to write your queries. If all your queries against the date column will be in the form `TRUNC(EVT_END)`, then you should use the FBI. However, in general it will be better to create an index on just `EVT_END` for the following reasons:

- It will be more reusable. If you ever have queries checking particular times of the day then you can't use TRUNC.
- There will be more distinct keys in the index using just the date. If you have 1,000 different times inserted during a day, `EVT_END` will will 1,000 distinct keys, whereas `TRUNC(EVT_END)` will only have 1 (this assumes that you're storing the time component and not just midnight for all the dates - in the second case both will have 1 distinct key for a day). This matters because the more distinct values an index has, the higher the selectivity of the index and the more likely it is to be used by the optimizer (see [this](http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_index_selectivity.html))
- The clustering factor is likely to be different, but in the case of using trunc it's more likely to go up, not down as stated in some other comments. This is because the clustering factor represents how closely the order of the values in the index match the physical storage of the data. If all your data is inserted in date order then a plain index will have the same order as the physical data. However, with `TRUNC` all times on a single day will map to the same value, so the order of rows in the index may be completely different to the physical data. Again, this means the trunc index is less likely to be used. This will entirely depend on your database's insertion/deletion patterns however.
- Developers are more likely to write queries against where trunc isn't applied to the column (in my experience). Whether this holds true for you will depend upon your developers and the quality controls you have around deployed SQL.

Personally, I would go with Marlin's answer of `TYPE, EVT_END` as a first pass. You need to test this in your environment however and see how this affects this query and all others using the TYPE and EVT_END columns however.